# Energy carried by matter waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

Does the square of amplitude of matter wave is proportional to the energy carried by the wave $mc^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ... and no.

Suppose you have a single particle in a wave like state i.e. delocalised and with a well defined momentum. This particle has some wavefunction $\psi$ and the amplitude squared is then $|\psi|^2$. But the particle has to be normalised so:

$$ \int |\psi|^2 dV  = 1 $$

That means the amplitude of the wave does not depend on the kinetic energy of the particle, but only on the normalisation condition.

But ...

When we think of a wave like a light wave this is a coherent state of many particles and in that case the integral of the state will give us the number of particles $n$:

$$ \int |\Psi|^2 dV  = n $$

And of course the energy is proportional to the number of particles present, so in this sense the amplitude squared is proportional to the total energy.

Comment: does it implies for 1 particle quantum mechanics ,its energy does not depend on amplitude and multi particle quantum mechanics its amplitude relates energy by square of amplitude isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the square of amplitude of matter wave is proportional to the energy carried by the wave mc2

There are no matter waves, in the sense of the energy of the particle "waving" in space and time. As John's answer says, there are probability waves, it is the probability  to find a particle at (x,y,z,t) that is derived by  solution of a quantum mechanical boundary condition problem, not the energy behavior. The particle appears whole.

This is evident in the one electron at a time [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles)

[image: dblsingleeel]

The dots on the first frame are the footprints of electrons, one at a time, they are not spread out all over the screen. The gradual accumulation shows the probability distribution of the experiment "electron scattering off two slits ". This shows the classical wave interference patterns.

Comment: I have to say I disagree with your opening comment. What is a Fock state if not a wave?

Comment: @JohnRennie It is a mathematical representation that integrated over will represent an electron. It is not an electron spread out in space. Those are within the HUP footprints of electrons, they are not waves in any reasonable way, except mathematically, where a set of complete functions can always fit a shape ( in this case the wavepacket of electron)